# How to use boolean to validate my function?

Tags: c++, validation, storage

Essentially I wanted to validate this code. I tried to put it in the main function but it wasn't looping back to the input. For example if you entered the note in the wrong form or started with a number I had an if statement in the code telling the user error...

But it skipped over to the second input instead of letting the user re-enter their note but I was told I needed to use boolean to validate but I actually don't know how to use boolean very well so an explanation of how to link it properly to the function would be helpful as well a couple of questions have been put in as comments (e.g // question:.....)

Question: How can I not repeat this code for validating the bass notes which is `notenameB` in this case ?

```
bool validatenotename (string notenameM)
    {
        if (notenameM.length() != 2 && notenameM.length() != 3)
        {
            cout<<"invalid number of characters, note must be between 2 or 3 characters (example: A1 or C#2) : \n";
            return false;
        }
        else if (notenameM[0] != "a" && notenameM[0] != "b" && notenameM[0] != "c" && notenameM[0] != "d" && notenameM[0] != "e" && notenameM[0] != "f" && notenameM[0] != "g")
        {
            cout<<"First character of a note should be one of the following (A,B,C,D,E,F,G) \n";
            return false;
        }
        //question: here i want to enter an if statement making sure that when the user enters c#,d#,f#,g#,or a# it will only allow those notes to be 3 characters (the third being a number for octaves) and also the user cant put a b# or e#?
        else if (
    }
do
{


cout << endl
<< " 1) Melody.\n"
<< " 2) Bass.\n"
<< " 3) Playback Melody.\n"
<< " 4) Playback Bass.\n"
<< " 5) Exit.\n"
<< " Choose one of the above and enter the corresponding number then press enter:  ";
cin >> choice;

switch (choice)
{
case 1: 

    { 
        string notenameM;
        int numbernotesM;
        float notelengthM;
        string notename;


        cout<<"Enter number of notes you want: ";
        cin>>numbernotesM;

        for( int i=0; i < numbernotesM; i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter note"<<i+1<<": ";
           cin>>notenameM;


        }


        for( int i=0; i < numbernotesM; i++)
        {
            cout<<"enter note length for "<<i+1<<": \n";
            cin>>notelengthM;

        }


    }

break;

case 2:
    {
        string notenameB;
        int numbernotesB;
        float notelengthB;
        string notename;

        cout<<"Enter number of notes you want: \n";
        cin>>numbernotesB;

            for( int i=0; i < numbernotesB; i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter note"<<i<<": \n";
        cin>>notenameB;
        }

        for( int i=0; i < numbernotesB; i++)
        {
            cout<<"enter note length for "<<i<<": \n";
            cin>>notelengthB;
        }
    }
break;
```

Comment: Please strip all the unnecessary code before posting here.

Comment: im not quite sure what is unnecessary i thought i only put what i thought is important code  ?

Comment: For example, any input seems unnecessary. You can hard-code the values that you envision the user to input.

Comment: thats the thing i am really confused about the inputting thats why i kept it in there i am assuming we are speaking of the consol input
i was wondering wether these CIN functions store the input in order ? also would it be more efficient using vectors ? since i want to build the program to eventually beep the notes out to the user

Comment: Your function in question takes a string and it doesn't care where that string comes from.

Comment: sorry mate i really dont get what you mean ?

Comment: You seem to want to write (part of) a function that returns true or false. In order to demonstrate that, you don't need the whole switch statement. All you need is this function and `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

In the below statement:

```
else if (notenameM[0] != "a" && notenameM[0] != "b" && notenameM[0] != "c"
        && notenameM[0] != "d" && notenameM[0] != "e" && notenameM[0] != "f" 
        && notenameM[0] != "g")
```

`notenameM[0]` is just a character which you are trying to compare with a string i.e `"a"` actually a string with additional null terminator as  `| a | \0 |` stored in the memory. Change all of them like `'a'`.

Comment: my code keeps coming up with an error i am yet to resolve error c2040: '!= : int  differs in levels of indirection from 'cont char [2]' whats that ?

Comment: what is cont? Do you mean const?

Comment: @kas I guess you are doing wrong comparison operations with string literals in double quotes instead of characters with single quotes.

Comment: yea it keeps comming up with many errors stating the same thing